# Dropdown Menu Keeps Extending with No Content

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown menu on my site with 5 items on it. After the fifth item, it keeps extending with the defined background color and goes to the bottom of the page. When I add height to the dropdown menu, it fixes the issue, but obviously, I can't add a height. I just want it to extend to the last item in the list. I have no idea why this is happening.

Tried adding defined height. This worked, and a scroll bar appeared on the side. This isn't a viable solution though unless height is 100% of whatever items are listed.

The menu is "onepress-menu-mobile" in this CSS code:

```
/* my own editing starts */

div.contact {
    margin-bottom:3vh;
}

div.contact p {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:4.5vh;
}

div.contact p.number,
div.contact p.number2,
div.contact p.email {
    margin-bottom:0px;
    line-height:1.4em;
}

div.contact p.number2 {
    font-size:2vh;
}

#about, #services, #gallery {
    padding-top:7vh;
    padding-bottom:2vh
}

#gallery {
    background:white;
}

div.section-desc {
    text-align: left;
}
div.section-desc li {
    margin: 0px 3vh 0px 8vh;
    color: black;
}
div.section-desc img {
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:20px auto;
    display:block;
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:1px;
    width:100%;
}

div.section-desc div.video {
    margin:20px auto;
}

div.section-desc .lastparagraph {
    font-size:3vh;
    margin:0px 5vh;
}

#main.site-main p {
    margin-left:3vh;
    margin-right:3vh;
}

.myself {
    float:left;
    margin:5px 22px 30px 10px;
    width:30vw;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
}

div.site-branding {
    margin-left:-25px;
}

p {
    font-size:18px;
    color:black;
}

#primary.content-area {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

a.site-text-logo:hover {
    color:#116ebf !important;
}

ul.onepress-menu a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px white;
    text-decoration:underline;
    transition: 0s;
    color:white;
}

ul.onepress-menu {
    color:white;
}

ul.onepress-menu.onepress-menu-mobile {
    background:black;
    height:100%;
}

.site-header {
    background: black;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
    background:white;
}

#nav-toggle.nav-is-visible span,
#nav-toggle.nav-is-visible span:before, 
#nav-toggle.nav-is-visible span:after {
    background:white !important;
}

.aboutme {
    margin-left:39% !important;
}

.arve-wrapper {
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#features div.feature-media {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#features h4 {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
#features {
    padding:20px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.hero-large-text {
    font-size:7.2vw !important;
}

div.hero__content p {
    font-size: 6.8vw;
    margin:0px !important;
    line-height: 7vh;
}

#hero div.container {
    padding-top:22% !important;
    padding-bottom:3% !important;
}

div.container {
    width:100%;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;
}
```

Comment: What is the data source for your menu? If it's an external data source like a database, it's probably getting the number of rows but the wrong field must be printed.

Comment: Have you aslo he HTML code? Please limit the to show only the code of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out. You don't have to reply to this question, I'm good.